# How to set a static window size ImGui?

Tags: c++, imgui

I am new to ImGui, and trying to set the max and min window size. I am using the example dx10 ImGui code. I understand that this line will set the width and hight of the window at the start to be 600*800:

`HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Micheal's Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 600, 800, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);`

How do I disable the user's ability to resize this window?

Comment: Dear ImGui is a UI llibrary. The code you posted has nothing to do with ImGui, but window creation via the Win32 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) as

```
(WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
```

where

```
WS_THICKFRAME   0x00040000L The window has a sizing border. Same as the WS_SIZEBOX style.
```

So, you need to clear `WS_THICKFRAME` bit in the window style:

```
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_THICKFRAME
```